# why can not access child fields using parent reference

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class A {
    int super_var = 1;
}

class B extends A {
    int sub_var = 2;
}

public class Demo{
    public static void main(String []args){        
        A a = new B();
        System.out.print(a.sub_var); //compile error
    }
}
```

why this will end with a compile error ? reference (a) referencing to an Object of B it has sub_var so why is it restricted ? why reference (a) can access only the fields in A ?

Comment: If you want the compiler to treat `a` as a reference to an object of type `B`, why are you declaring it as `A` in the first place? Just remember that the compiler doesn't care how you initialized `a` - it *only* thinks of the value as being a reference compatible with `A`.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have these classes:

```
public class Animal() {
    // ...
}

public class Fish extends Animal() {
    public void swim() {...}
}
```

If you declared an `Animal`:

```
Animal x = new Fish();
```

and you called the `swim()` method

```
x.swim();
```

**Would you expect it to work?** I don't think so, because not every animal can swim. That's why you have to explicitly specify that the animal `x` is a `Fish`:

```
((Fish) x).swim();
```

**In your case**, if you wanted to call that method, you should specify (technically, it's called *cast*) the type:

```
System.out.print(((B)a).sub_var);
```

**Note:**

- This works similar for methods and variables. I used a method in the example since it's more illustrative.

**Edit:**

Let's see this example:

```
Animal x;

if (some_condition)
    x = new Fish();
else
    x = new Cat();

x.swim();
```

This restriction exists, because Java won't know if, at execution time, the object assigned to x will have the method `swim()`. So to avoid this, you have to cast to the respective type to call a method that doesn't exist in superclass.

Comment: thank you for the answer. yes x.swim(); can not be call but how this restriction for the parent class references achieve ?

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha I hope I understood your question. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

At first it does sound like it should work. (And in some languages it probably does.) But think about this example:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String []args){        
        A a = new B();
        print( a );
    }

    public static void print( A arg ) {
        System.out.print(arg.sub_var); //compile error
    }
}
```

This functionally does the same thing but the print is in another method. If your version worked, this one could be expected to work too.

But what if someone then does this?

```
Demo.print( new A() );
```

This should fail because `A` doesn't have a `sub_var`. It would have to throw some kind of runtime error instead.

So the design decision in Java was not to allow this and if you declare a local variable/field/method parameter as type `A`, then you can only access things that every object that is either `A` or a subclass is guaranteed to have.

If you want to access more, you need to cast it to the subclass, which **will** throw an exception if you try it on an object that doesn't fit.

```
A a = new A(); 
System.out.print(((B)a).sub_var); //ClassCastException is thrown here
```

Comment: yes true. thank you for the answer. but i want to know how Java was not to allow this ?

Comment: How? The compiler simply ignores everything but the declared type of the variable, which in your case is `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access B members with the reference of Parent object A.

Instead change your `println` statement like below to access,

```
System.out.print(((B)a).sub_var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a variable called sub_var in the parent class ? No. That is why you get the error -

```
sub_var cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

See this

```
System.out.print(a.super_var); //okay
System.out.print(a.sub_var); //compile error
```

Answer (score 0):

you create an object of type B and assign it to a variable of type A. The type A does not declare sub_var. This field is declared only in type B. the compiler only sees what is declared in type A, although the variable is instantiated to an object of type B.

If you want to access sub_var you would have to cast a to B.

System.out.println( ((B)a).sub_var);

Answer (score 0):

The `sub_var` is in `class B`, so you can only access through a reference of `class B`. To the compiler  `A a = new B();` means `a` is an instance of `class A`.